# Why does it say "'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command" Even though I have set the right PATH variable for flutter

Tags: windows, flutter

[Screenshot of Command Prompt and Flutter PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUZIX.jpg)

Comment: Your `PATH` is now broken because you **replaced** it with flutter's location. Instead you need to **append** flutter's location to your `PATH`.

Comment: How do I get the original address so I can append flutter's address to it?

Comment: Surely one of the more than 7,500 results of [a search for this error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command) would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the PATH variable, click apply. Then close the Command Prompt and reopen it. Then run `flutter doctor`